# How does the definition of the regulator work?

Tags: matrices, field-theory

If we create a $r x (r+1)$ matrix with entries $N_jln(|\sigma_j(u_i)|)$ with $N_j$ being 1 if $\sigma_j$ is a real embedding and 2 if its complex, any $r x r$ submatrix generated by deleting a column will have the same determinant regardless of column choice. I'm confused on how this works though, I know the sum of all rows is equal to 0 but I don't understand how this implies that the $rxr$ submatricies will have equal determinant.
If we have $a+b+c=0$ and $d+e+f=0$, I dont see why or how $\begin{vmatrix}a&b\\d& e\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}a&c\\d& f\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}b&c\\e& f\end{vmatrix}$. Maybe I'm just missing something obvious, but was hoping someone could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Note that (where the vertical bars simply mean determinant, not absolute value of the determinant) $\begin{vmatrix}a & b \\ d &e\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}a & a+b\\d & d+e\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix} a & -c \\ d &-f\end{vmatrix}=-\begin{vmatrix}a & c \\d &f\end{vmatrix}$.